# NGINX rewrite condition issues

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have a location on my nginx server like /folder/. In that folder there are .jpg files and a .php script.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

When a user accesses a url like: http://mywebsite.com/folder/10-11 nginx will search for 10-11 file, 10-11.png file, 10-11.jpg file and display it (if the file is on the server). This section works just fine.

Now when a user accesses the same url, if the file does not exist I want the user to be redirected to that php script.

Bellow is the part of the nginx config which works. All the image files in that folder are like 10-10, 21-19, 90-20 etc (2 digit number - 2 digit number).

```
location /app/comics/lqthumb/ {
                try_files $uri /$uri.png /$uri.jpg;
}
```

The other nginx section should look like this:

```
location /app/comics/lqthumb/ {
        rewrite ^/app/comics/lqthumb/(.*?)-(.*?)$ /app/comics/lqthumb/thumbgen.php?chapter=$1&page=$2 permanent;
    }
```

The ideea is to combine this rule together. How can I do an if else statement or something similar? I have tried several combination, read a lot of forum posts or even answers from here but I cant make it work.

If you have questions please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You combine these by using a named location. The last element of a `try_files` can invoke a default action to enter a named location to process the rewrite.

```
root /path/to/root;

location /app/comics/lqthumb {
    try_files $uri $uri.png $uri.jpg @thumbgen;
}
location @thumbgen {
    rewrite ^/app/comics/lqthumb/(.*?)-(.*?)$ /app/comics/lqthumb/thumbgen.php?chapter=$1&page=$2;
}
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
```

I have removed the spurious `/` you placed before `$uri`. I assume you have a location which invokes the PHP interpreter, otherwise, you could put those directives into the named location. I wasn't sure if you intended the redirect to be `permanent`. With no flag an internal redirect is performed transparently to the user.

See [try_files documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was pretty close but I was doing something wrong. I was adding a / at the end of the location then a =404 after @thumbgen and a / before $uri. Probably that was the issue!